# how to create custom aggregation for python

Tags: python, pandas

I dont know how to create a custom aggregation for my dataset and was wondering if someone can help me understand how to make it work.

an example one-liner code to compute a mean would be:

```
dataset.groupby('variable').value.mean()
```

this would take the mean of all my values and group them by 'Variable'.

what if I have Value1 and Value2, and I want to sum and  divide value1 and value2 instead?

so in words, it would be:

```
dataset.groupby('variable').(sum(value2)/sum(value1))()
```

or something like that.  obviously, that doesn't work, but I was wondering if someone can help me understand how to create custom aggregation and apply it to the group by above.

Comment: See my answer below. You should always post an example and a piece of your dataset in order to be provided with more accurate answers. It's hard to work in the air.

Answer (score 0):

This should what you want:

```
dataset.groupby('variable')['value1','value2'].agg('sum')
result = dataset['value2'].sum() / dataset['value1'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom functions with `apply()`. Something like this:

If my dataset looks like this :

```
dataset

value1  value2  variable
1       2       1
2       2       1
3       2       2
4       2       2
```

```
def cust_func(data):
    return data["value2"].sum()/data["value1"].sum()

dataset.groupby("variable").apply(cust_func)
```

Output will look like this:

```
variable
1        1.333333
2        0.571429
```